# How to remove view link under a user name from the user list table of the same user role in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove view link under a username whose user role is same as the current user role. For example if the current user is agent_admin then remove view link from all the agent_admin users from the user list table. I am trying to use the following code but it removes view link from all the users.Please help me to solve this problem.

```
function pa_user_list_pay_link( $actions, $user_object ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'agent_admin', $user_object->ID ) )
        unset( $actions['view'] );
    return $actions;
}

add_filter( 'user_row_actions', 'pa_user_list_pay_link', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

`user_row_actions` hook passes the `WP_User` object which you can use to check user capability.

```php
add_filter('user_row_actions', function($actions, $user_object) {
    if ($user_object->has_cap('agent_admin') && current_user_can('agent_admin'))
        unset($actions['view']);

    return $actions;
}, 10, 2);
```

The above code has not been tested but I feel confident it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Miroslav for your help. This worked for me.